# Efficiently count the number of primitive roots in all moduli up to $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, primitive-roots

Let's define $f(n)$ as the number of primitive roots modulo $n$. That is, $f(n) = \begin{cases}\varphi(\varphi(n))&n=1,2,4,p^k,2p^k\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. We want to efficiently calculate $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)}$. we can notice that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)} = \sum_{3\leq p\leq n \\ p\text{ prime}} {\varphi(p-1)} + \sum_{3\leq p\leq \frac n2 \\ p\text{ prime}} {\varphi(p-1)} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{p\text{ odd prime}\\p^k \leq n} {p^{k-2}(p-1)\varphi(p-1)} + \sum_{p\text{ odd prime}\\2p^k \leq n} {p^{k-2}(p-1)\varphi(p-1)}\right) + 1_{n\geq 1} + 1_{n\geq2} + 1_{n\geq4}$$
It's easy to calculate $$ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{p\text{ odd prime}\\p^k \leq n} {p^{k-2}(p-1)\varphi(p-1)} + \sum_{p\text{ odd prime}\\2p^k \leq n} {p^{k-2}(p-1)\varphi(p-1)}\right) + 1_{n\geq 1} + 1_{n\geq2} + 1_{n\geq4} $$ in time $\tilde O(n^\frac12)$, so the problem is equivalent to calculating $\sum_{p\leq n\\p\text{ prime}} \varphi(p-1)$ efficiently. Is there any way to do that, say in $O(n^{1 - \varepsilon})$ time? The function $\varphi(p-1)$ doesn't seem to have any useful identities which could let us efficiently calculate the sum.

We can write $$\sum_{p\leq n\\p\text{ prime}}{\phi(p-1)} = \sum_{p\leq n\\p\text{ prime}}{\sum_{d | p-1} {\mu(d) \frac nd}} = \sum_{dq < n \\ dq+1\text{ prime}}{\mu(d) q} = \sum_{d \leq n-1} {\mu(d) \sum_{q \leq \frac {n-1}d} 1_{dq + 1 \in \mathbb{P}} q} = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{n-1}} {\mu(d) \sum_{\sqrt{n-1} < q \leq \frac {n-1}d} 1_{dq + 1 \in \mathbb{P}} q} + \sum_{q \leq \sqrt{n-1}} {q \sum_{d \leq \frac {n-1}q} 1_{dq + 1 \in \mathbb{P}} \mu(d)}$$
The first addend seems like it could be calculated using a Meissel-Lehmer style algorithm for each $d$, but I'm not sure about the second addend, $\sum_{q \leq \sqrt{n-1}} {q \sum_{d \leq \frac {n-1}q} 1_{dq + 1 \in \mathbb{P}} \mu(d)}$.

Given $n, q$, how efficiently can we calculate $\sum_{d \leq \frac {n-1}q} 1_{dq + 1 \in \mathbb{P}} \mu(d)$?

Alternatively, like in the Meissel–Lehmer algorithm we can define
$$\phi(n, m) = \sum_{p \leq n\\v | p \implies v=1\lor v>m} {\varphi(p-1)}$$
but I can't see any recursion for this function, compared to the Meissel-Lehmer one, because $\varphi(p-1)$ doesn't seem to have any simple relation to $\varphi(pq-1)$.

Comment: $\sum\phi(p-1)$ is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A333315 and there are some links to the literature that might be worth a look.

Comment: Find anything helpful at that link, Command?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, the paper it links to only calculates its asymptotics, and doesn't say anything about exact calculation

Comment: Maybe there isn't any efficient way to do an exact calculation.